# Content inside viewpager is moving left and right on scrolling left or right

Tags: android

I have used a simple viewpager and added three fragment inside it. By default Viewpager support horizontal scrolling. When i swipe viewpager and reach to the last fragment, so technically it will not swipe further in same direction. But in my case after reaching to last fragment when i swipe it moves the layout of current fragment out of the screen.
[Issue that i am facing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGdEW.png)

Comment: How you have disabled viewpager swipe? Can you add code?

Comment: Same problem i am facing even if i am not disabling the swipe and using the simple viewpager. In that case that problem ocured in first and last page of viewpager

Comment: If you want to disable scroll of viewpager then this code will work.

Comment: yes. but my problem is that content inside viewpager fragment is moving out of the screen on doing left or right

Answer (score 0):

**This is a non-swipable_viewPager** you can just implement by this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMyScroller();
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMyScroller();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

//down one is added for smooth scrolling

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
    public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

      private boolean enabled;

      public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
          this.enabled = true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         if (this.enabled) {
              return super.onTouchEvent(event);
         }

         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         if (this.enabled) {
             return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
         }

         return false;
      }

      public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
          this.enabled = enabled;
      }
}
```

hope it will help for you